# 'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' While trying to open spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I upgraded my Spyder Install recently and it stopped working altogether. I tried some solutions mentioned online like upgrading qt and trying to open a new instance but nothing helped so far. This is the output I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==5.2.0', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 232, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 41, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 47, in check_qt
    if parse_version(actual_ver) < parse_version(required_ver):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 114, in parse_version
    return packaging.version.Version(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/packaging/version.py", line 296, in __init__
    match = self._regex.search(version)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I am running Arch linux. Any Help would be wonderful.

Comment: How is spyder installed? Since you're on arch this looks very much like a partial upgrade problem.  `pacman -Syu` to start with...

Comment: Oh and *how* did you upgrade it?  In general on arch you should always `pacman -Su pkgname` rather than `pacman -S`: "partial upgrades are not supported".  If your spyder is from the aur, rebuild it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this error is coming up when I type spyder into my terminal, I upgraded the package using the methods mentioned here and the error still persists. The issue is probably with the version parameter as is mentioned in the error. can anybody help me with that?